# Rails 3.2.8 Record `save' method execute without errors,but didn't change the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the output in rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
irb(main):001:0> u=User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: "scorpio_et", passwd: "xxx", updated_at: "2013-01-07 12:09:26",expire_time: "2000-01-01 12:09:15">
irb(main):002:0> u.expire_time=Time.now
=> 2013-01-07 20:16:39 +0800
```

then i execute u.save , from the output it seems worked

```
irb(main):003:0> u.save
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "expire_time" = '2013-01-07  12:16:39.628766', "updated_at" = '2013-01-07 12:16:42.816250' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
  (85.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

But when i fetch from the database , the `expire_time' field didn't change

```
irb(main):004:0> User.first
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: "scorpio_et", passwd: "xxx",  updated_at: "2013-01-07 12:16:42", expire_time: "2000-01-01 12:16:39">
```

When I use `save!' ,it didn't throw exception,and the output is identical with the`save' .But I can update other field .
Here is the schema.rb:
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130107073652) do

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "passwd"
    t.string   "jsoncookie"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.time     "expire_time"
 end
```

I notice the `expire_time' field is`time',but I think it should be `datetime'

my migration is :
    class AddExpireTimeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :users, :expire_time, :datatime
      end
    end

Comment: Do you get an exception if you call `u.save!`?  If so, could you please add that error info to your question.

Comment: Are you using `rails console` command to load the rails environment? If yes, Is there any constraint in your User model for the `expire_time` field that restricts the update access. Also, Try to update any other field to check whether it gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record gets updated (compare the time `12:09:15` -> `12:16:39`) but looks like the `expire_time` has `time` type, not `datetime`. So date part is not stored in the db.

Comment: Yes,I just found that i misspelled `datetime` to `datatime`.Think you all very much